# How to create a vertical button in the flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

im try to created a verticle button on the left center screen in the flutter. First i created a Raised Button and rotate it using Rotated Box. But it keeping padding left side of the button. i dont want padding on the left side.  How to possible it ?

```
  body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: RotatedBox(
                  quarterTurns: 1,
                  child: RaisedButton(padding: EdgeInsets.all(0), color: Clr.primaryClr, onPressed: () {}, child: Text('SPORTS')))),
          pages[currentPage],
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: You want the text to be vertical, or horizontal and rotated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove padding of button with:

`RaisedButton(materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap)`